# Compute the lowest int which is not in a List<int>

Tags: c#, list, search, find

I have a quite short `List<int>`:

```
var list = new List<int> {0, 4, 1, 3};
```

The list is not sorted.
I need to find the lowest integer, starting from 0, which does not belong to the list.
At the moment I use the following algorithm:

```
int x = 0;

while (list.Contains(x))
   x++;

// In this example it must be: x = 2
```

The algorithm is pretty simple, but it is not linear O(n), and I need to compute this value a huge number of times using different lists.

How can I speed up this method?

Comment: What are your limitations? You only want speed at the cost of memory? How many numbers can there be?

Comment: Does ordering is important? Does the list has to allow duplicates? If not you can use `HashSet<T>` which provides O(1) `Contains` operation, otherwise use a Sorted collection..

Comment: If you're only missing a single number then you can sum the numbers in the list and then subtract them from the equivalent list of all N numbers.

Comment: @flindeberg There can be at most 100 integers in the list. At the moment I'm interessted in increasing the speed of the algorithm by reducing its computational cost. Obviously I'll use a tradeoff between speed and memory.

Comment: @Nick Have a look at my proposed solution then, I'm assuming the list is given and cannot be changed, also I'm assuming that the list can contain doubles. If doubles are not present in the list it is possible to speed it up a bit.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel ordering is not important and duplicates do not affect the result.

Comment: @Nick Then use `Hashset<T>` and see the difference.

Comment: @Nick: What's the maximum *value* in the list? Is that 100 as well?  Have you actually checked that the simple approach is causing you a problem?

Comment: @JonSkeet I really do not have a specific upper bound, it depends from several factor, so I'll try to avoid improvments basing on this. I can only say that the numbers start from 0 and the list is most of the time quite small (2 order of magnitude).

Comment: Right, so if the lists are small, does it really matter if the algorithm is quadratic?

Comment: @JonSkeet I was hoping there was a way to make it linear, or at most O(n log(n)).

Comment: Why though? You may well find that the constant factors involved in a linear solution (e.g. creating a hash set) outweigh the cost of the simple quadratic solution. Algorithmic complexity is only about how time/space trends as the size increases - for small sizes, other factors can easily dominate. Again, have you actually tried this with realistic data and found it to be a problem? Simple code is better than clever code until you've determined that you actually have a problem you need to fix.

Comment: @JonSkeet you're right, I know that for small sizes, other factors have to be considered. And yes, I profiled my code and for 10000 lists it takes about one second: it could be too much.

Comment: @Nick: 10,000 lists of only a few items? That sounds like it shouldn't take a second... note that if you were *profiling* rather than *benchmarking*, that could easily affect things. It would help if you'd include the code you're using to try to test this within the question, so that we could test alternatives.

Comment: Having just run a test myself on my laptop, it takes about half a second for 10,000 iterations with a list which has 100 elements, 0-99... i.e. your worst case. If the list is smaller or it's missing one of the earlier values, it would clearly be faster. Do you have specific performance targets at this point?

Comment: @JonSkeet [My profile](http://s7.postimg.org/5abfalszf/Senza_nome.png) takes about one second because I also consider how the list is created (the GetNeighborsID method, where colors is my list). I used Visual Studio and the image shows the results. Here the complete code http://pastebin.com/5BBEEkfx. Thanks for your time.

Comment: So have you investigated how much of the time is being spent in the bit of code that you've asked about in this question? If that's only (say) 20% of the time, then even if you could make it instantaneous you wouldn't get a huge overall boost.

Comment: @JonSkeet As you can see from the image http://s30.postimg.org/5f98w6af5/Senza_nome.png the profile results are: Contains() 55.4% and GetNeighborsID() 44.6%.

Comment: Right. So even if you make it instantaneous, that's only going to halve the time. (And obviously you're not really going to be able to make it instantaneous.) Again, do you have concrete performance requirements?

Comment: Looking at your complete code, I strongly suspect there's a lot that can be optimized - but it's hard to tell what the code is trying to achieve. For example, it's odd for a method which is commented as "Gets the neighbors color" to return a `List<int>` - an int isn't a color, and the description suggests it would return a single value, not a collection...

Comment: I've got some ideas for improving this... but I can't test it without sample data. If you can provide a *complete* example, I'll see what I can do.

Comment: I'm not a native english speaker, I'm sorry for these miscomprehension. However can you tell what are the parts that can be strongly optimized and how?

Comment: @JonSkeet Actually points will be read from a database which I don't have yet. For now I'm using random data: http://pastebin.com/3WQ4vBYJ

Comment: First issue then: your benchmark is unreproducable. Your `dist` value is random, which could *radically* change the results, if I understand everything correctly. Why not hard-code that, and give the `Random` in `RandomPoints` a fixed seed? Then you can get consistent results to compare with different code.

Comment: @JonSkeet Sure, that's a good point.

Comment: Also, given that you're just using `Random.Next()` for the x/y/z values, you'll hardly have *any* neighbours which are close together. It feels like you really need to get some more realistic data and put together a concrete performance requirement before it's worth changing the code significantly.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing too much about your actual limitations, maybe this could be a solution:

```
int breakpoint = 153; // Or whatever number you've  found is the breakpoint

int FirstMissingNumber(List<int> list)
  IEnumerable<int> toIterateOver = list;
  if (list.Count > breakpoint)
    toIterateOver = new HashSet<int>(list);

  int i = 0;
  while (toIterateOver.Contains(i))
   i++;
  return i;
}
```

Note though that for smaller lists the overhead of creating the hashset surely is larger than the `O(1)` speed gain on `Contains()`.

EDIT:
Added a breakpoint "switch", you have to manually find out where the breakpoint is in your environment though.

Comment: You don't need to check for `Contains` before adding, `Hashset` does that for you. It won't allow duplicates

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Wasn't aware of that, ty. I thought it threw an exception.

Comment: `Add()` will return false indicating that element already exist :)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Indeed it does, just checked it up on msdn, then the solution is really simple actually :)

Comment: Actually I do not have any advantage by using HashSet in place of List. The elapsed time is the same for me.

Comment: @Nick Interesting, I thought there would be some since you possibly could be iterating a hundred times over the list. But if your list often is smaller the overhead of creating a hashset would not be worth it.

Comment: @Nick: That just goes to prove my point - your lists are too small for it to make a difference. If you had a list of the values 0-999999 for example, then it *would* make a difference.

Comment: @Rahul Maybe I was unclear, the breakpoint is the size breakpoint for when it's quicker to to a hashset rather than naive list iteration, i doesn't have to do with the elements in the list.

Comment: @Nick Added a simplistic switch, try to find if the added `if` is worth it in your case. Having some real life examples would really help in giving you better advice.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just sort the list and loop through it to find out the missing number like below

```
        var list = new List<int> { 0, 4, 1, 3 };
        list.Sort();

        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            if (!list.Contains(i))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Missing {0}", i);
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I'll try, but I don't think this can help: sort the list increase the computational complexity.

Comment: Without sorting the list as well, the code works fine. If you sort the list then you can check `if(i != list[i])` and no need of `Contains()` list function.

Comment: Just to point, the above solution should be bounded to `O(n)` complexity even without sort. Cause the loop goes for `0 .. n-1` but in the worst case where the last element in list is the missing element the complexity would be `O(n)` else see in code I am breaking out of the loop and so it should be bounded to O(n).